# Trying to show hidden content on resize

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am currently using isotope to help me resize and relayout a set of boxes. When it resizes one of the divs I would like to replace the contents with a hidden div.

Here is some of the code to give an idea:

```
$('#container-2').isotope({
    childSelector: '.child-big',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 468
    };
});


$('.child-big').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('tall')) {
        tileStyle = {
            width: 468,
            height: 150
        };
    }
    else {
        tileStyle = {
            width: 468,
            height: 190
        };
    }

    $this.toggleClass('tall');

    $this.find('.child-content').stop().animate(tileStyle);

    $('#container-2').isotope('reLayout')

});​
```

And a bit more of the code, if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/Mx6KH/4/

I am not sure how to get it to switch. In an earlier version of this project I had been using jQueryUI's addClass and removeClass functions but I am not sure if that's still appropriate with this set-up or if there is a simpler way to accomplish it; that was getting a bit unwieldy.